# Using AJAX validation to check ListBox entry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax validation extender with the ListBox. On submitting the form, the validator must check if atleast one entry of the ListBox has been chosen or not. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28VS.80%29.aspx)(the ValidatorCalloutExtender is not responsible for the validation) to validate if the user selected at least one item of the ListBox. Here is an example: [MSDN/RequiredFieldValidator.InitialValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx):

```
     <asp:ListBox id="list"runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Value="Australia">Australia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" value="NoCountry">--ChooseCountry--</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="USA">USA</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:ListBox>

      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="valList"
           ErrorMessage="Selection Invalid!"
           ControlToValidate="list"
           InitialValue="NoCountry" runat="server"/>
```